# Excel - Why did select * SQL statement omit a field?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql

I have a question regarding using SQL in Excel. I have an Excel application that obtains data from a Worksheet and import the data to another Worksheet.

[Entry form image here. Note the Entry Date field.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZhHj.png)

An SQL statement with Select * was used to import the data. However, when I execute the SQL, all the data manage to import except one date field. There are 2 date fields in the entry form but only one manage to import while the other is completely blank. I check the format for it on both worksheets and made sure that they're the same but still nothing.

[When executed, Entry Date is empty.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCtdp.png)

Does anyone know what causes this?

For reference here is the code I use to link entry form to the display in VBA.

```
Sub testsql(AB As String)

Dim rgPlaceOutput As Range    'first cell for the output of the query
Dim stSQLstring As String     'text of the cell containing the SQL statement
Dim rg As String, SQL As String

If AB = "1st" Then
stSQLstring = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Inner Workings").Range("B2").Text
Set rgPlaceOutput = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("1st Summary").Range("A2")
End If

QueryWorksheet stSQLstring, rgPlaceOutput, ThisWorkbook.FullName, AB
End Sub
```

The SQL code is written in my Excel Sheet as seen in my 2nd screenshot. The VBA only grabs the code from the cell I stated. The SQL code is:

```
select * from EntryTable
```

Comment: You'll need to show your table schema and column definitions, disclose the method of exporting as well, and I'm sure some other detail to get help with this more than likely... I've not run into this problem you explain but maybe someone else has; otherwise, please [edit] and disclose more detail such as how you are exporting, what you see when you select from SQL SSMS or MySQL WB, etc., the data types on your table as well, and I'm sure other detail but quickly that's what I can think of quickly.

Comment: Please don't post your actual sub,  but modify it to have a minimum working example: remove everything which is not related to the issue abs include which is related (e.g. SQL expression is missing from your code).

Comment: I imagine this has something to do with the other variables being the same, your Project No, Die No, Description and Entry date are the same for the last field and the missing field. 
I would try manually changing each, one at a time, to see if this is a bug in your SQL.

Comment: The Die No, Description and Entry Date are all obtained via Vlookup based on Project No. When I removed the formula and key in the Entry Date with a random string it can import. But when I key in date it won't import. Why is this specifically happening to Entry Date and not to normal Date? Also I started working on this program yesterday and this issue only appeared today. I had no problems with it originally and I don't recall tampering with the code whatsoever.